# vectorized upper bound for segmented data in CUDA / thrust

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I have the following input data:

```
e = 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 1 1 1
t = 1 1 4 4 4 5 | 1 6 7
i = 0 1 2 3 4 5 | 6 7 8 // indices from [0,n-1]
```

The data is first sorted by `e`, then by `t`. `e` is the key which identifies segments in the data. In this case:

```
segment_0 = [0,5]
segment_1 = [6,8]
```

Each segment is again segmented by `t`. In this case:

```
sub_segment_0_0 = [0,1] // t==1
sub_segment_0_1 = [2,4] // t==4
sub_segment_0_2 = [5,5] // t==5

sub_segment_1_0 = [6,6] // t==1
sub_segment_1_1 = [7,7] // t==6
sub_segment_1_2 = [8,8] // t==7
```

I want to create the following output sequences:

```
f = 2 2 5 5 5 6 | 7 8 9
l = 6 6 6 6 6 6 | 9 9 9
```

`f` contains the start index of the next sub_segment within the current segment.

`l` contains (the end index of the last sub_segment within the current segment) + 1.

For the last sub_segment of each segment both values should point to its end index.

In order to calculate `f`, I tried using `thrust::upper_bound`, but this only works if I have just one sub_segment:

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/binary_search.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>  
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

#define PRINTER(name) print(#name, (name))
template <template <typename...> class V, typename T, typename ...Args>
void print(const char* name, const V<T,Args...> & v)
{
    std::cout << name << ":\t";
    thrust::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, "\t"));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t e[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
    uint32_t t[] = {1,1,4,4,4,5};
    uint32_t i[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};

    int size = sizeof(i)/sizeof(i[0]);
    typedef thrust::host_vector<uint32_t> HVec;
    typedef thrust::device_vector<uint32_t> DVec;
    HVec h_i(i,i+size);
    HVec h_e(e,e+size);
    HVec h_t(t,t+size);
    DVec d_i = h_i;
    DVec d_e = h_e;
    DVec d_t = h_t;
    PRINTER(d_e);
    PRINTER(d_t);
    PRINTER(d_i);

    DVec upper(size);
    thrust::upper_bound(d_t.begin(), d_t.end(), d_t.begin(), d_t.end(), upper.begin());
    PRINTER(upper);

    return 0;
}
```

**output**:

```
d_e:    0   0   0   0   0   0   
d_t:    1   1   4   4   4   5   
d_i:    0   1   2   3   4   5   
upper:  2   2   5   5   5   6
```

If I use the input data containing two sub_segments, it won't work anymore, since there is no `thrust::upper_bound_by_key`:

```
// replace in the code above
uint32_t e[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1};
uint32_t t[] = {1,1,4,4,4,5,1,6,7};
uint32_t i[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

**output**

```
d_e:    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   
d_t:    1   1   4   4   4   5   1   6   7   
d_i:    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   
upper:  2   2   7   7   7   7   2   8   9
```

---

How would a `upper_bound_by_key` be implemented for my data?

And how can I efficiently calculate `l`?

I am open to any solution, thrust is not a necessity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way to do this.

In order to be able to use `lower_bound`, I needed to make sure that `t` is **globally** sorted. In order to do that, I first find out the starting points of each 
sub_segment using `adjacent_difference`. After that, `scatter_if` copies increasing numbers from a `counting_iterator` for each starting point of a subsegment. Finally, `inclusive_scan` spreads same values for each subsegment. I combined the two steps before the `inclusive_scan` into the custom functor `my_scatter` to achieve better kernel fusing.

Now `upper_bound` is applied to these globally increasing values to calculate `f`.

`l` can be calculated by applying `upper_bound` on `e`.

I am not sure how the efficiency of my approach compares to the approach presented by @RobertCrovella.

---

**output**:

```
d_e:    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   
d_t:    1   1   4   4   4   5   1   6   7   
d_i:    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   
norm_t: 0   0   2   2   2   7   13  20  28  
d_f:    2   2   5   5   5   6   7   8   9   
d_l:    6   6   6   6   6   6   9   9   9
```

---

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/binary_search.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>  
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/adjacent_difference.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/scatter.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>

#define PRINTER(name) print(#name, (name))
template <template <typename...> class V, typename T, typename ...Args>
void print(const char* name, const V<T,Args...> & v)
{
    std::cout << name << ":\t";
    thrust::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, "\t"));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <typename IteratorType, typename IndexType = uint32_t>
struct my_scatter : public thrust::unary_function<IndexType,IndexType>
{
    my_scatter(IteratorType first) : first(first)
    {
    }

   __host__ __device__
   IndexType operator()(const IndexType& i)
   {
      IndexType result = i;
      if (i > static_cast<IndexType>(0) && *(first+i) == *(first+i-static_cast<IndexType>(1)))
      { 
          result = static_cast<IndexType>(0);
      }
      return result;
   }

   IteratorType first;
};

template <typename IteratorType>
my_scatter<IteratorType> make_my_scatter(IteratorType first)
{
  return my_scatter<IteratorType>(first);
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t e[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1};
    uint32_t t[] = {1,1,4,4,4,5,1,6,7};
    uint32_t i[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

    int size = sizeof(i)/sizeof(i[0]);
    typedef thrust::host_vector<uint32_t> HVec;
    typedef thrust::device_vector<uint32_t> DVec;
    HVec h_i(i,i+size);
    HVec h_e(e,e+size);
    HVec h_t(t,t+size);
    DVec d_i = h_i;
    DVec d_e = h_e;
    DVec d_t = h_t;    
    PRINTER(d_e);
    PRINTER(d_t);
    PRINTER(d_i);

    DVec norm_t(size);

    auto my_scatter_op =  make_my_scatter(zip(d_e.begin(), d_t.begin()));
    auto ti_begin = thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), my_scatter_op);
    auto ti_end = thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(size), my_scatter_op);
    thrust::inclusive_scan(ti_begin, ti_end, norm_t.begin());
    PRINTER(norm_t);

    DVec d_f(size);
    thrust::upper_bound(norm_t.begin(), norm_t.end(), norm_t.begin(), norm_t.end(), d_f.begin());    
    PRINTER(d_f);

    DVec d_l(size);
    thrust::upper_bound(d_e.begin(), d_e.end(), d_e.begin(), d_e.end(), d_l.begin());    
    PRINTER(d_l);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your computation of `f` does not take into account `e` at all. Therefore I assume that the "case" I mentioned where an e-segment consisting of only one t-segment either does not occur, or else I have some misunderstanding about how you label t-segments (it appears that the first t-segment in any e-segment will be labelled 1).  Not that this is important - I believe you could extend your approach in a straightforward way to handle `e` in this fashion, if needed.

Comment: @RobertCrovella you are right, I now supply `zip(d_e.begin(), d_t.begin())` to my functor to make it work in these cases as well

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible approach:

1. Mark the end of your (t-)segments.  I assume that it's possible for an e-segment to have a single t-segment.  If that's the case, then adjacent e-segments could have t-segments of the same numerical value (1 presumably).  Therefore marking the end of segments needs to consider both `e` and `t`.  I use a method basically like adjacent difference, except it considers both `e` and `t` using `thrust::transform` and shifted representations of `e` and `t`.
2. Determine the value that `f` will hold for each segment.  Now that we know the end of each (t-)segment, we can simply pick the next value out of `i` (using `copy_if`, and the segment end markers as our stencil) as the `f` value for the preceding segment.  To facilitate this, and since your `i` is just an index sequence, I create an `i` vector that is one element longer than what you have shown.
3. Create a numerically increasing index for each segment.  This is just an exclusive scan on the vector created in step 1.
4. Use the index sequence created in step 3, to "scatter" the `f` segment values created int step 2, into our `f` result ("scatter" is done with `thrust::copy` and a permuation iterator).

Here's a worked example, borrowing from your code:

```
$ cat t835.cu
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>


using namespace thrust::placeholders;

struct my_semarker_func
{
template <typename T>
  __host__ __device__
  uint32_t operator()(const T &d1, const T &d2){
    if (thrust::get<0>(d1) != thrust::get<0>(d2)) return 1;
    if (thrust::get<1>(d1) != thrust::get<1>(d2)) return 1;
    return 0;}
};


#define PRINTER(name) print(#name, (name))
template <template <typename...> class V, typename T, typename ...Args>
void print(const char* name, const V<T,Args...> & v)
{
    std::cout << name << ":\t";
    thrust::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, "\t"));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t e[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1};
    uint32_t t[] = {1,1,4,4,4,5,1,6,7};

    int size = sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0]);
    typedef thrust::host_vector<uint32_t> HVec;
    typedef thrust::device_vector<uint32_t> DVec;
    HVec h_e(e,e+size);
    HVec h_t(t,t+size);
    DVec d_i(size+1);
    DVec d_e = h_e;
    DVec d_t = h_t;
    thrust::sequence(d_i.begin(), d_i.end());
    PRINTER(d_e);
    PRINTER(d_t);
    PRINTER(d_i);

// create segment end markers
    DVec d_s(size,1);
    thrust::transform(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_e.begin(), d_t.begin())), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_e.end()-1, d_t.end()-1)), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_e.begin()+1, d_t.begin()+1)), d_s.begin(), my_semarker_func());
// create segment f values
    DVec d_g(size);
    thrust::copy_if(d_i.begin()+1, d_i.end(), d_s.begin(), d_g.begin(), _1 == 1);
// create segment indices
    DVec d_h(size);
    thrust::exclusive_scan(d_s.begin(), d_s.end(), d_h.begin());
// create f
    DVec d_f(size);
    thrust::copy_n(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d_g.begin(), d_h.begin()), size, d_f.begin());
    PRINTER(d_f);

    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -o t835 t835.cu
$ ./t835
d_e:    0       0       0       0       0       0       1       1       1
d_t:    1       1       4       4       4       5       1       6       7
d_i:    0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
d_f:    2       2       5       5       5       6       7       8       9
$
```

A very similar sequence could be used to create the `l` vector.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Can you comment on how the efficiency/performance compares to my approach?

Comment: Efficiency in thrust is frequently all about data movement, especially for algorithms like this one (not much computation). Fusion of operations in thrust attempts to improve efficiency by reducing the data movement.  You can pretty much compare the efficiency by counting the reads and writes per element by each algorithm. Allocations also cost. I haven't done all that arithmetic, but it looks like your case should be faster, especially if you don't `USE_MY_SCATTER`.  It takes you one allocation and two thrust operations to get the 'f' vector. For me it requires 3 allocations and 4 operations.

Comment: "especially if you don't `USE_MY_SCATTER`": do you think my custom functor is worse than using multiple thrust algorithms sequentially? if yes, please explain in detail since I thought the exact opposite.

Comment: Sorry, got tripped over the infndef. Instead of "especially if you don't `USE_MY_SCATTER`" I should have said, "especially if you use the path selected when `USE_MY_SCATTER` is defined" or just "especially if you `USE_MY_SCATTER`".  (my operations plus allocations count was based on that path, obviously)  But honestly, I haven't counted the load/store operations exactly, and it seems quite simple to benchmark the difference.  The analysis process is tedious. For me, using the tools seems quicker and more reliable than relying on my understanding, heuristics, or mental short-cuts.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will benchmark using my real data.