# How to overcome memory limitation during VBO indices computation using thrust::lower_bound()

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I generate a mesh using Marching cubes on GPU (using CUDA). The mesh is very detailed and the crude list of vertices are stored on the GPU in a VBO mapped to CUDA array `float *d_vertexData`. The data order is vertex position and normal interleaved as shown below.

`{v0x, v0y, v0z, n0x, n0y, n0z, v1x, v1y, v1z, n1x, n1y, n1z, ...}`

The size of the mesh usually ranges from 34MB(500K Triangles)~1400MB(20M Triangles) and is stored on the GPU.

I then use `thrust::sort()`, `thrust::unique` to get rid of duplicate vertices and use `thrust::lower_bound()` to compute the indices. After this step, the mesh size is reduced by 70% or more. The code below demonstrates this step.

```
float exampleVerts[36]=
{ 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 0, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0,
4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 0, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1, 0};

unsingned int numVertices = 36;
cudaMalloc(void**(&d_vertexData), numVertices*sizeof(float));
cudaMemCpy( d_vertexData, exampleVerts, numVertices*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

unsigned int data_size = numVertices * 6; //6 floats per vertex

thrust::device_ptr<float> vertsPtr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_vertexData);

thrust::device_vector<float> vertsCopy(vertsPtr, vertsPtr + data_size);
thrust::device_vector<unsigned int> indices(numVertices);

auto zip_vert_first = zip(...); // using vertsPtr and strided_range
auto zip_vert_last = zip(...); // using vertsPtr and strided_range

thrust::sort(zip_verts_first, zip_verts_last);
auto new_vert_last = thrust::unique(zip_vertex_first, zip_vertex_last);

auto zip_vertcopy_first = zip(...); //using vertsCopy.data() and strided_range
auto zip_vertcopy_last = zip(...); //using vertsCopy.data() and strided_range

//find index of each input vertex in the list of unique vertices
thrust::lower_bound(zip_vert_first, new_vert_last,
    zip_vertcopy_first, zip_vertcopy_last,
    indices.begin());
```

It works but has a rather huge memory requirement. This line `thrust::device_vector<float> vertsCopy(vertsPtr, vertsPtr + data_size);` requires [VBO size] memory to store a copy of vertices for use in `thrust::lower_bound()`.

In my application the meshes are usually very large upwards of 1.5GB for a list of crude vertices. This method has the following limitation.

> It requires additional 117% of VBO size.
>   (100% for the copy of all vertices, 17% for indices)

Due to this limitation, this method can't be run on a GPU with 2GB or lower VRAM. I am using a GPU with 4GB of VRAM, even then I easily reach this limit in my application.

Is there any other way to compute the indices on GPU without this huge memory requirement? else my only option is to go back to the CPU (host) which I believe will be very slow.

Comment: You should provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for questions like this.  Not asking for your whole code.  It wouldn't have to much longer than what you've shown already.  Data can be synthetic, doesn't need to be actual vertex data.  It's quite likely that the copy of the data you are making in `vertsCopy` is completely unnecessary, but I can't give a crisp answer without a crisp question to work with.  Having said all that, `thrust::sort` requires O(n) temporary storage, so sorting 1.5GB of data will still require over 3GB available memory.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for the comment. I do need a copy of the input vertices for use in `thrust::lower_bound()` since the values in the original array are unique and sorted `thrust::sort()` and `thrust::unique`. I compute the indices by using `thrust::lower_bound` with copy of original vertices and the unique ones. This is an extension to the [weld_vertices.cu example code](https://code.google.com/p/thrust/source/browse/examples/weld_vertices.cu) for 2D vertices. if `thrust::sort` requires O(n) storage, do I really need over 4.5GB of memory for processing 1.5GB dataset?

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the copy of the vertices if you operate on indices instead of the vertex data itself.

The following example (based on my [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31162986/678093) and my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31221858/678093)) does the following steps:

1. Sort the vertices and the indices in one step
2. Find start indices of duplicate vertices
3. Remove duplicate vertices based on these start indices
4. Calculate new indices

The final indices are stored in `d_indices_2`.

---

**output**

```
d_vertices:     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   1   2   
d_indices:      0   1   2   3   4   5   
d_vertices:     0   1   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   4   5   6   7   8   9   7   8   9   
d_indices:      5   0   1   3   2   4   
d_indices_2:    0   1   2   0   4   0   
d_vertices:     0   1   2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
d_indices_3:    0   1   2   2   3   3   
d_indices_2:    1   2   3   2   3   0
```

---

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/tuple.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/scatter.h>
#include <thrust/unique.h>
#include <thrust/remove.h>
#include <stdint.h>

template<typename... Iterators>
__host__ __device__
thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<Iterators...>> zip(Iterators... its)
{
    return thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(its...));
}

template <typename Iterator, typename thrust::iterator_difference<Iterator>::type stride>
class strided_range
{
public:
    typedef typename thrust::iterator_difference<Iterator>::type difference_type;

    //template <difference_type stride>
    struct stride_functor : public thrust::unary_function<difference_type,difference_type>
    {
        __host__ __device__
        difference_type operator()(const difference_type& i) const
        { 
            return stride * i;
        }
    };

    typedef typename thrust::counting_iterator<difference_type>                           CountingIterator;
    typedef typename thrust::transform_iterator<stride_functor, CountingIterator> TransformIterator;
    typedef typename thrust::permutation_iterator<Iterator,TransformIterator>             PermutationIterator;

    // type of the strided_range iterator
    typedef PermutationIterator iterator;

    // construct strided_range for the range [first,last)
    strided_range(Iterator first, Iterator last)
        : first(first), last(last) {}

    iterator begin(void) const
    {
        return PermutationIterator(first, TransformIterator(CountingIterator(0), stride_functor()));
    }

    iterator end(void) const
    {
        return begin() + ((last - first) + (stride - 1)) / stride;
    }

protected:
    Iterator first;
    Iterator last;
};


template<typename, typename>
struct append_to_type_seq { };

template<typename T, typename... Ts, template<typename...> class TT>
struct append_to_type_seq<T, TT<Ts...>>
{
    using type = TT<Ts..., T>;
};

template<typename T, unsigned int N, template<typename...> class TT>
struct repeat
{
    using type = typename
        append_to_type_seq<
            T,
            typename repeat<T, N-1, TT>::type
            >::type;
};

template<typename T, template<typename...> class TT>
struct repeat<T, 0, TT>
{
    using type = TT<>;
};

template<typename Tuple> struct std_to_thrust_tuple;
template<typename...T> struct std_to_thrust_tuple<std::tuple<T...>> {
  using type = thrust::tuple<T...>;
};

template<typename IteratorType, std::size_t stride>
class zipped_strided_range
{
public:

    typedef typename strided_range<IteratorType, stride>::iterator SingleIterator;
    typedef typename repeat<SingleIterator, stride, std::tuple>::type StdIteratorTuple;
    typedef typename std_to_thrust_tuple<StdIteratorTuple>::type IteratorTuple;
    typedef decltype(thrust::make_zip_iterator(IteratorTuple())) ZipIterator;

    zipped_strided_range(IteratorType first, IteratorType last) : first(first), last(last)
    {
        assign<0>();
    }

    ZipIterator begin() const
    {
        return thrust::make_zip_iterator(begin_tuple);
    }

    ZipIterator end() const
    {
        return thrust::make_zip_iterator(end_tuple);
    }

protected:

    template <std::size_t index>
    void assign(typename std::enable_if< (index < stride) >::type* = 0)
    {
        strided_range<IteratorType,stride> strided_range_iterator(first+index, last-(stride-1)+index);

        thrust::get<index>(begin_tuple) = strided_range_iterator.begin();
        thrust::get<index>(end_tuple) = strided_range_iterator.end();
        assign<index+1>();
    }

    template <std::size_t index>
    void assign(typename std::enable_if< (index == stride) >::type* = 0)
    {
        // end recursion
    }

    IteratorType first;
    IteratorType last;

    IteratorTuple begin_tuple;
    IteratorTuple end_tuple;
};




#define PRINTER(name) print(#name, (name))
template <template <typename...> class V, typename T, typename ...Args>
void print(const char* name, const V<T,Args...> & v)
{
    std::cout << name << ":\t";
    thrust::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, "\t"));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


template <typename IteratorType, typename IndexType = uint32_t>
struct my_scatter : public thrust::unary_function<IndexType,IndexType>
{
    my_scatter(IteratorType first) : first(first)
    {
    }

   __host__ __device__
   IndexType operator()(const IndexType& i)
   {
      IndexType result = i;
      if (i > static_cast<IndexType>(0) && *(first+i) == *(first+i-static_cast<IndexType>(1)))
      { 
          result = static_cast<IndexType>(0);
      }
      return result;
   }

   IteratorType first;
};

template <typename IteratorType>
my_scatter<IteratorType> make_my_scatter(IteratorType first)
{
  return my_scatter<IteratorType>(first);
}

template <typename T>
struct my_transformer : public thrust::unary_function<T,T>
{
  __host__ __device__
  T operator()(const T& x) const 
  {
    return static_cast<bool>(x);
  }
};


int main()
{
    using namespace thrust::placeholders;

    const int stride = 3;
    const int num = 6;

    const int size = stride * num;

    float values[size] = {1,2,3,
                          4,5,6,
                          7,8,9,
                          4,5,6,
                          7,8,9,
                          0,1,2
    };


    typedef uint32_t Integer;

    thrust::host_vector<float> h_vertices (values, values+size);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_vertices = h_vertices;
    float* dev_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vertices.data());
    zipped_strided_range<float*, stride> zipped(dev_ptr, dev_ptr+size);

    thrust::device_vector<Integer> d_indices(num);
    thrust::sequence(d_indices.begin(), d_indices.end());

    PRINTER(d_vertices);
    PRINTER(d_indices);

    // 1. sort 
    auto zip_begin = zip(zipped.begin(),d_indices.begin());
    auto zip_end   = zip(zipped.end(),d_indices.end());
    thrust::sort(thrust::device, zip_begin, zip_end);
    PRINTER(d_vertices);
    PRINTER(d_indices);

    thrust::device_vector<Integer> d_indices_2(num);

    // 2. find start indics of duplicate vertices
    auto my_scatter_op =  make_my_scatter(zipped.begin());
    thrust::transform(thrust::make_counting_iterator(static_cast<Integer>(0)),
                      thrust::make_counting_iterator(static_cast<Integer>(num)),
                      d_indices_2.begin(),
                      my_scatter_op);
    PRINTER(d_indices_2);

    // 3. remove duplicate vertices
    /*
    // unique could be used, but we already know which vertices we want
    auto new_end = thrust::unique(thrust::device, zipped.begin(), zipped.end());
    */
    auto new_end = thrust::remove_if(thrust::device, zipped.begin()+1, zipped.end()+1, d_indices_2.begin()+1, !_1);
    int new_size = (new_end - zipped.begin());
    d_vertices.resize(stride*new_size);
    PRINTER(d_vertices);

    thrust::device_vector<Integer> d_indices_3(num);
    auto transform_op = my_transformer<Integer>();
    auto t_b = thrust::make_transform_iterator(d_indices_2.begin()+1, transform_op);
    auto t_e = thrust::make_transform_iterator(d_indices_2.end(), transform_op);
    thrust::inclusive_scan(t_b, t_e, d_indices_3.begin()+1);
    PRINTER(d_indices_3);

    // 4. calculate final indices
    thrust::scatter(d_indices_3.begin(), d_indices_3.end(), d_indices.begin(), d_indices_2.begin());
    PRINTER(d_indices_2);


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This method requires 2 additional index buffers which is definitely less than 1 additional vertex buffer copy. but assuming the vbo size is huge(eg 1.5GB) the indices would need (0.25GB per buffer), according to Robert Crovella, sort in this case would require (3.5GB+) and another (0.5GB) for the 2 extra index buffers. This is crossing the 4GB mark :-(.

Comment: @Harish a) do the normals `n0x, n0y, n0z` really have to be taken into account when finding duplicate vertices? b) you could try to compress your vertex data (see e.g. [here](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/145366-Compressed-Vertex-Arrays?p=1043103&viewfull=1#post1043103) ) or compress the normals ([see e.g. here](http://aras-p.info/texts/CompactNormalStorage.html))

Comment: @Harish you could also apply the method above sequentially on subsets of the data. this involves of course more compute and memory overhead but your memory constraints could be met. BTW: the temporary storage necessay for the sort algorithm should be freed after the sort is done, so it might just work out

Comment: I believe you could sort *just an index array* with a specialized functor that used the index array to map into the vertex array.  This should get the sort memory usage down to ~0.5GB for the sort (half of which is freed on exit).  The original vertex array is not sorted using this approach, but if you then wanted to sort it, you could simply use a permutation iterator copy.  This step will *still* require 3GB, 1.5GB for input and 1.5GB for output.  But you could also just *never* sort the vertex data, and just reference it using the sorted indices when you need the sorted version.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Never sorting vertex data is not an option since there are a lot of redundant vertices (roughly 60%). I use `thrust::unique()` to get rid of redundant vertices. Exploring the index sorting method from m.s.

Comment: @Harish I guess what Robert meant ist that you can calculate the indices for a reduced mesh (so that the duplicate vertices are assigned to the same index) without sorting the mesh itself. Then several indices  point to the same vertex in the "non-unique" mesh. However, this might result in a lot of cache misses during rendering.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that @m.s. I now understand Robert's suggestion properly. I am trying to tackle multiple problems together. Reducing the VBO size, computing Indices and getting a good rendering cache hit rate. I am running into more problems with regards to the memory. It seems the sort operation is using up graphics memory that is not free'd on completion. If I can't solve the memory issue I'll make an MCVE and post it in another question.